# VBA Macro Concatenation for Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a requirement like I have some values in column A and I have multiple values in column B,C,D. If my column contains value `X` then I want to column header and column A value to be concatenate.

For example
[image]

I have gone through lots of question on Stack Overflow and I didn't found anything helpful.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Went on a VBA beginner's guide?

Comment: No I didn't get anything @Pierre

Answer (score 1):

please try this code.

```
Sub FindValues(ByVal WhereToFind As Range, ByVal WhereToPaste As Range)
    'where to find should have the header and values
    Dim col As Integer  'loop through columns
    Dim row As Integer  'loop through rows
    Dim a() As Variant
    Dim b() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    a() = WhereToFind

    For row = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
    For col = 2 To UBound(a, 2)
        If a(row, col) = "x" Then
          i = i + 1
          ReDim Preserve b(1 To i)
          b(i) = a(1, col) & "=" & a(row, 1)
        End If
      Next
    Next
    WhereToPaste.Resize(UBound(b)).Value = Application.Transpose(b())
End Sub
```

that should be called like

```
Sub caller()
FindValues ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E4"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1")
End Sub
```

the output is like

[image: sample output]

Comment: Getting an error like when i m running the code, can you explain me what is WhereToPaste.Resize(UBound(b, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(b())

Comment: updated the post. will try this as i send this commend

Comment: No It is giving error like "Invalid Procedure call or argument"

Comment: Getting same error like "Invalid Procedure call or argument "